# Setting up multiple different sites with Github Pages

Tags: github, web, github-pages

I can't seem to find a definitive answer to this.

I would like to purchase the Developer package on Github and set up multiple static sites on completely different custom domains (not subdomains).  For example, with one Github Developer account (username: SampleUsername), create a blog about horses (horsesblog.com), a blog about cats (catsblog.com) and a blog about dogs (dogsblog.com).

The key here is that they are all on separate private project repositories within the SampleUsername account and are completely independent of each other.

Is this possible?

Comment: Have you read [this](https://help.github.com/articles/user-organization-and-project-pages/)? I think you're looking for project pages with [custom domains](https://help.github.com/articles/using-a-custom-domain-with-github-pages/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running multiple sites on [different apex domains](https://help.github.com/articles/setting-up-an-apex-domain/) in GitHub Pages is entirely possible!

You just need to [add the relevant A](https://help.github.com/articles/setting-up-an-apex-domain/#configuring-a-records-with-your-dns-provider) records (or ALIAS/ANAME is supported) for the domain.

Comment: So I don't need a CNAME record in my Namecheap custom DNS?

Thanks

Comment: @GiacomoLawrance Woops, sorry! You should actually use [A records](https://help.github.com/articles/setting-up-an-apex-domain/#configuring-a-records-with-your-dns-provider) instead. You just use CNAME records for subdomains :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, appreciate it!